# How to clear an item value in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have an iFrame with several items and i want to update a record.

```
const frame = await page.frames()[1];
const P1_CUSTOM_NAME = await frame.$('#P1_CUSTOM_NAME');
await P1_CUSTOM_NAME.type('MyFavoritCustomer', {delay: 20});
```

This will not overwrite the field `P1_CUSTOM_NAME`. Unfortunately it appends the value `'MyFavoritCustomer'`.

Any suggestions how i can clear an item value?

Comment: ok, i found a possible solution.                                                                async function setSelectVal(sel, val) {
        frame.evaluate((data) => {
             return document.querySelector(data.sel).value = data.val;
         }, {sel, val})
      }

      // updates
     await setSelectVal('#P1_CUSTOM_NAME', 'Hans');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete existing text from input using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631057/how-to-delete-existing-text-from-input-using-puppeteer)

Answer (score 4):

Try a triple click to focus and select all.

```
const frame = await page.frames()[1];
const P1_CUSTOM_NAME = await frame.$('#P1_CUSTOM_NAME');
await P1_CUSTOM_NAME.click({clickCount: 3});
await P1_CUSTOM_NAME.type('MyFavoritCustomer', {delay: 20});
```