# How to delete existing text from input using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm trying to test amending text in an editable input which contains the title of the current record - and I want to able to test editing such text, replacing it with something else.

I know I can use `await page.type('#inputID', 'blah');` to insert "blah" into the textbox (which in my case, having existing text, only appends "blah"), however, I cannot find any page methods[1](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-class-page) that allow deleting or replacing existing text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear an item value in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907941/how-to-clear-an-item-value-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can use `page.evaluate` to manipulate DOM as you see fit:

```
await page.evaluate( () => document.getElementById("inputID").value = "")
```

However sometimes just manipulating a given field might not be enough (a target page could be an SPA with event listeners), so emulating real keypresses is preferable. The examples below are from [the informative issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/761) in puppeteer's Github concerning this task.

Here we press `Backspace` as many times as there are characters in that field:

```
const inputValue = await page.$eval('#inputID', el => el.value);
// focus on the input field
await page.click('#inputID');
for (let i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
  await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
}
```

Another interesting solution is to click the target field 3 times so that the browser would select all the text in it and then you could just type what you want:

```
const input = await page.$('#inputID');
await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })
await input.type("Blah");
```

Comment: **await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })** , that is interesting! Just like we use browser!

Comment: Be aware that the triple click solution this will not work with textareas containing multiple lines, as that will only highlight one.

Comment: @vsync 2 clicks select just one word and 3 clicks select all the text in an input, which is what the question is about :)

Comment: The Backspace idea is nice, but now (Puppeteer 2) it must be ```await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');``` instead of ```await page.press('Backspace');```

Comment: the * page.keyboard.press('Backspace')* is the only method that works for me (using react), maybe because it is more "Blackbox" / reliable than just changing the value, meaning, some updates won't happen if you just change the value of an element.

Comment: `await input.click({ clickCount: 4 })` for multiline select

Comment: this example with `keyboard.press('Backspace')` should call out that you may need to run `await page.click('#inputID')` first so input is focused, otherwise your backspace might not do anything

Answer (score 33):

You can use the [`page.keyboard`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-keyboard) methods to change input values, or you can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

**Replace All Text:**

```
// Using page.keyboard:

await page.focus('#example');
await page.keyboard.down('Control');
await page.keyboard.press('A');
await page.keyboard.up('Control');
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
await page.keyboard.type('foo');

// Using page.evaluate:

await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  example.value = 'foo';
});
```

**Append Text:**

```
// Using page.keyboard:

await page.focus('#example');
await page.keyboard.press('End');
await page.keyboard.type(' bar qux');

// Using page.evaluate:

await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  example.value += ' bar qux';
});
```

**Backspace Last Character:**

```
// Using page.keyboard:

await page.focus('#example');
await page.keyboard.press('End');
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');

// Using page.evaluate:

await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  example.value = example.value.slice(0, -1);
});
```

**Delete First Character:**

```
// Using page.keyboard:

await page.focus('#example');
await page.keyboard.press('Home');
await page.keyboard.press('Delete');

// Using page.evaluate:

await page.evaluate(() => {
  const example = document.getElementById('example');
  example.value = example.value.slice(1);
});
```

Comment: The Mac equivalent for the Windows Control + A is Command + A.

Comment: For cross-platform keyboard solutions, you could instead use `page.keyboard.down('Shift')`, `page.keyboard.press('End')`, followed by `page.keyboard.press('Backspace')`

Comment: Replace all text doesn't work with Mac because ctrl + A keystroke in Mac would not select the entire text but instead place the cursor at the start of the field

Answer (score 15):

If you are not interested in simulating any key events, you could also use puppeteer's [page.$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) method as a concise means to remove the textarea's value...

```
await page.$eval('#inputID', el => el.value = '');
await page.type('#inputID', 'blah');
```

...or even completely replace the value in one step, without simulating the subsequent typing:

```
await page.$eval('#inputID', el => el.value = 'blah');
```

Answer (score 6):

This works perfect for "clear only" method:

```
const input = await page.$('#inputID');
await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Keyboard API](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-class-keyboard) which simulates keystrokes:

```
await page.focus(css);            // CSS selector of the input element
await page.keyboard.down('Shift'); 
await page.keyboard.press('Home');
await page.keyboard.up('Shift');  // Release the pressed 'Shift' key
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace');
```

This keystroke is cross-platform as opposed to using ctrl + A(does not work in Mac to select all characters in a input field)

Comment: I replaced 'Home' with 'End' and this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

above answers has an ESLint issues.
the following solution passing ESLint varification:

```
await page.evaluate(
  (selector) => { (document.querySelector(selector).value = ''); },
  inputBoxSelector,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most clean way for me is:

- Setup

```js
const clearInput = async (page, { selector }) => {
  const input = await page.$(selector)
  await input.click({ clickCount: 3 })
  await page.keyboard.press('Backspace')
}
```

- Usage

```js
const page = await context.newPage()

await clearInput(page, { selector: 'input[name="session[username_or_email]"]' })
await clearInput(page, { selector: 'input[name="session[password]"]' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason you want to delete existing text generally may be want to replace it.

You can use `page.evalute`

```js
let title = getTitle()
let selector = getSelector()

await page.evaluate(
  ({selector, title}) => {
    let el = document.querySelector(selector)
    if ('value' in el) el.value = title
    else el.innerText = title
  },
  {selector, title}
)
```

Answer (score -3):

`someField.type("");`

Pass the empty string before typing your content.

This worked for me.